# How to integrate angular2-froala-wysiwyg npm plugin with Nativescript Angular2 app?

Tags: angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I need to provide rich text editor UI in my Nativescript Angular2 app.

I have searched and got the followed link. Is it possible to integrate angular2-froala-wysiwyg npm plugin with Nativescript Angular2 app?

- angular2-froala-wysiwyg - "https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-froala-wysiwyg#use-with-angular-cli"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, It is not possible to integrate angular2-froala-wysiwyg npm plugin with Nativescript Angular2 app.

because angular2-froala-wysiwyg plugin does `DOM manipulation` nativescript doesn't support Html dom manipution. that  is why you can't use any plugins which interact with html dom in anyway.

but you can use all the plugin which is purely JS based and does not use dom manipulation event a bit.

Comment: source for what? you can not use angular-froala-wysiwyg plugin because it is constructed using standard html. nativescript has it's own set of tag only which can be used. that is why you can't use standard html based plugins.